# Recognize set/lose Focus-Event in QWindow

Tags: qt, focus, tableview, qt-quick, qwindow

I´ve created a Qt-Quick Combo-Box that, when it will be pressed, opens a QWindow, in which I show the content within a TableView. The problem is, the focus on the TableView can´t be set.

So first question is: How can I set the Focus on my TableView (which is hosted inside my QWindow)?

Furthermore, I have to get the event, if the user clicks beside the QWindow or outside the Application. That means the focus was changed and I can close my QWindow.

So second question is: How can I get the information, that the TableView lost the focus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you use setFocus to set the focus? To recognize that the focus has been lost, you have to derive the class and override the focusOutEvent or write an eventfilter.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

For from QWidget derived classes:

To set a focus use setFocus.

To recognize that the focus has been los, you can derive the class and override focusOutEvent or write an eventfilter.

Comment: to write the answer in the traditional way.